# Remove ESLint from React project

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I configured ESLint to my project using `eslint --init`, it's configured to my project.

Now I want to remove that from my project because it's showing unnecessary errors over the project.

How to remove the initiated ESLint from my project?

Comment: Rather than removing it, why not configure it to apply the rules you *do* care about?

Comment: Unnecessary errors? If ESLint catches issues it won't stop the project from being built, and fixing those issues will help the long-term health of the project and your own professional development. There's no good reason to remove it unless you're replacing it with something similar. I learned a staggering amount from using JSLint, and while ESLint is less fussy than that it's still incredibly beneficial, and can fix *many* issues for you automatically.

Comment: It sounds like you *added* eslint, not *configured*. If you configured you would not be getting "unnecessary" errors. Ultimately **you** decide what errors eslint reports

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Basically, just delete `.eslintrc` and any other eslint config files(if any) from the project.

Also, check your package.json and delete all eslint packages and do npm install on your project.

Also, if you are using vscode, you can disable it [with a simple setting](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/123#issuecomment-243613973)

Answer (score 3):

You will have to remove the `.eslintrc` file and also remove the devdependencies `eslint`, `eslint-plugin-react` from your package.json